# Magento dataflow import (stop indexing on the fly)

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, indexing, reindex

There are, basically,  two ways when importing product via csv file in Magento. 
a) import 
b) dataflow import

a) option, works faster, I assume that is because this option want index all the data on the fly, you have to do that after the import is done.

is there a way i can stop dataflow import to stop indexing on the fly. I think this will speed up the process of importation. Very important.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the indexes mode to Manual Update instead of Update on Save.

Also setIsMassupdate product flag is used in DataFlow import to prevent indexer to be triggered upon each product save method call.

Comment: sorry. but it did not help. As it was set to manual at the first place. Did not solve anything. Thanks anyway :=)

Comment: Did you added the setIsMassupdate flag?

Comment: Where to add the setIsMassupdate flag?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone tryign to disable the cache-clearing / indexing thats done after an import then go to file `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php` and comment out the line `$batchModel->beforeFinish();`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a module to override `Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch` with `MyModule_Override_Dataflow_Model_Batch`. Overriden `beforeFinish()` and commented out `$adapter->finish();`.

This stops the pesky `Please wait while the indexes are being refreshed.` from happening.